# WHERE IN Array SQL

Tags: php, sql, where-in

Update: if sched_id = 2 {Output user1,user2,user4,user5 }

Can you help me with this guys..Bcoz Now when i run the code only the 1st number can be found using WHERE IN .. or is there another way to get / search value in array sql to use in WHERE.. Thank you!

[Click to view the IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUCNS.jpg)

```
     <?php

 $dbServername = "localhost"; //servername
 $dbUsername = "root"; //database username
 $dbPassword = ""; //database password
  $dbName = "test_db"; //database name

 //Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);

  if(isset($_POST["sched_id"]))  
  { 

 $sched_id = $_POST["sched_id"];

?>
  <!-- Col-12 -->
        <div class="col-md-12">

          <?php

           $sql = "SELECT user.Schedule_ID, user.FullName FROM user

            WHERE $sched_id IN (Schedule_ID) AND user.UserType = 0";
           $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
           $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results);

            ?>
           <div class="row">
           <?php
           foreach ($results as $i => $result) :
             $rows = ceil(count($result) / 3); 
           ?>
             <?php if($i % $rows === 0 && $i !== 0): ?>
             </div><div class="row">
           <?php endif;?>

           <div class="col-sm-4">
            <?php echo $result['FullName']; ?>
           </div>
           <?php endforeach;?>

        </div>

      </div>

   <?php } ?>
```

where Schedule_ID is compose of array values.

Comment: Please edit your question to include all code and errors as formatted text within the question, not as an image.

Comment: What is the type of these columns? You will get a better answer to your question if you read the guidance and formulate a question in an appropriate format.

Comment: From where are you running that command?

Comment: thank you  for answering.. sorry im new in stack overflow please bare with me thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with [`FIND_IN_SET(str,strlist)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT user.Schedule_ID, user.FullName 
FROM user 
WHERE 
FIND_IN_SET($sched_id, user.Schedule_ID) > 0
AND user.UserType = 0
```

Comment: Thank You @TinhNQ This solve the problem. Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: @Jun glad that helped! happy coding